# Spring Boot TrayIcon is disappearing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i've got a weird Problem, I got a Application that creates a TrayIcon on startup. Now I refactored the App to Spring Boot and the TrayIcon disappears if I hover it with the Mouse but the App is running normally in the backround. I stripped down the Code to the essentials but the Problem still remains. Maybe somebody know what I'm doing wrong?

My Main Class is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoRepositories
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Application.class.getName());
        boolean bDebug = false;
        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class);
        builder.headless(false);
        builder.run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    TrayTest trayTest() {
        if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            System.out.println("SystemTray is not supported");
            return null;
        }
        Tray customTray = new Tray();
        try {
            customTray.setup();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return customTray;
    }
}
```

My Tray Class is this:

```
public class TrayTest extends TrayIcon {
    private static final String IMAGE_PATH = "/images/icon.png";
    private static final String TOOLTIP = "Tooltip";


    public TrayTest() {
        super(createImage(IMAGE_PATH, TOOLTIP));
    }

    public void setup() throws AWTException {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
        this.setPopupMenu(popup);
        SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(this);
    }

    protected static Image createImage(String path, String description) {
        URL imageURL = CustomTray.class.getResource(path);
        if (imageURL == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return new ImageIcon(imageURL, description).getImage();
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried this and removed the bean from the main class:

```
@Component
public class TrayTest extends TrayIcon {
    private static final String IMAGE_PATH = "/images/icon.png";
    private static final String TOOLTIP = "Tooltip";


    public TrayTest() {
        super(createImage(IMAGE_PATH, TOOLTIP));
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void setup() throws AWTException {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
        this.setPopupMenu(popup);
        SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(this);
    }

    protected static Image createImage(String path, String description) {
        URL imageURL = TrayTest.class.getResource(path);
        if (imageURL == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return new ImageIcon(imageURL, description).getImage();
        }
    }
}
```

edit: Also if I set a Breakpoint into TrayTest's setup function step over the "SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(this);"-call, the TrayIcon is created, I right click on the Icon and then I step over in the debugger the PopupMenu (I removed it in TestC Class) opens and if i continue execution it disappears along with the Icon.

**Solution**:
After long debugging i found out what was wrong, my Application got a ProcessManagement-Component which closed the Process which places the Icon in the TaskBar.